# NodeJS using Cluster to run a function in parallel

Tags: node.js, async.js, nodejs-server, node-cluster

My server receives a list base64 image eg [img1,img2....] at an endpoint.

I have function getPoses(img) that takes an image and returns an object back.

I want to be able to map the images to getPoses() and get the object back for each image in Parallel.

I have tried Async.each function but I notice it's not really Parallel. Probably because it runs in a single thread/core.

I have also tried to use cluster, so that I can utilize all the cores to run getPoses() in multiple cores. But I feel stuck because, It's not clear to me how the master can obtain the poses found by workers.

I would be super gratefully for any help from the community.

Aync code:

```
//END POINT
app.post('/postImage' ,async function(req,res){
    const imgBase64List = req.body.imgBase64.split('next');
    const imgBase64IndexList = []
    imgBase64List.map((imgBase64,index)=>{
        imgBase64IndexList.push([index,imgBase64])
    })
    async.each(imgBase64IndexList , getPoseDetection , function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error occured when feteching one of the pose")
            console.log(err)       
        }else{
            console.log('Sending Poses!')
            res.send(JSON.stringify(poseDetectionResults))
        }

    })



});//End of app.post and asyn function
```

```
const getPoseDetection = async (imgBase64Index, callback) => {
    //console.log('start');

    const img = new Image();
    img.src = imgBase64Index[1];
    const imgIndex = imgBase64Index[0]


    const canvas = createCanvas(img.width, img.height);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    const input = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas);
    const imageScaleFactor = 0.3;
    const flipHorizontal = false;
    const outputStride = 8;

    const poses = await net.estimateMultiplePoses(input, {
        flipHorizontal: false,
        maxDetections: 2,
        minPoseConfidence: 0.15,
        minPartConfidence:0.1,
        nmsRadius:20,
        });

    boundingBoxes = [] //reset the boundingBoxese
    poses.forEach(pose => {
        var box = posenet.getBoundingBoxPoints(pose.keypoints);
        boundingBoxes.push(box)
    });  

    poseDetectionResults[imgIndex] = {detectionList:poses}
    //console.log(poses)

}
```

Thank You

Comment: Can you share the async part of your code. Beacause you can easly execute your code parallel with async - await commands in nodeJS. I can share example code from my own project if you want

Comment: @AbdullahDeliogullari, I have shared the code where I have use the Async module

Comment: As ı understand your should add await to res.send. To help you, here is an example project with async requests https://github.com/AbdullahDeliogullariCS/UnderLined-Backend.